# Implement Update() method in a class derived from List(T) Class (System.Collections.Generic)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to be able to update a list by calling a method in my PersistentList instance.

```
public class PersistentList<T> : List<T> where T : class, new()
{
    public void Update(T Item){//...}
}
```

so Instead of :

```
public ActionResult Edit(Article a)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {                
        Article old = la.Find(p => p.Id == a.Id);
        int index = pl.IndexOf(old);
        pl[index] = a;             
        pl.SaveChanges();
        return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else { return View(); }
}
```

I want something like

```
public ActionResult Edit(Article a)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {                
        pl.Update(a);  //I'll call SaveChanges() in it.
        return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else { return View(); }
}
```

I'm a little lost. Any tips would be nice! Thank you

This is what I tried so far :

```
public void Update(T item)
{
    T old = base.Find(p => p.GetHashCode() == item.GetHashCode());
    int index = base.IndexOf(old);
    base[index] = item;            
    SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: It seems like the problem is how to know that `T` has the `Id` property right?

Comment: Also what is `la` and what is `pl`?

Comment: I think `la` is `List<T>` & `pl` belongs to `PersistentList<T>` instance, both `T` parameter may refer to `Article` class.

Comment: Yes, I don't what property of the predicate should I use and the T cannot be in the Matching Context of T Find(Predicate<T> match);(. :S

Comment: Does the first example even compile? Before refactoring existing code you´ll need some code that just *works*.

Comment: it does work Yes! I Just wanted to add the update method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an interface **for your items to derive from** containing the `Id` property:

```
public interface IItem
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And have another generic constraint for your list on it:

```
public class PersistentList<T> : List<T> where T : class, new(), IItem
{
    public void Update(T item)
    {
        // T must derive from the interface by constraint
        T old = base.Find(p => p.Id == item.Id);
        int index = base.IndexOf(old);
        base[index] = item;
        SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess instead of using 
var old = la.Find it should be    var old = base.Find ?

Comment: @MousKamel - I don't know - that depends on your logic - it is hard to know from your members' names what they are for. But the collection you use the `Find` should be of `T` so to get these constraints on it

Comment: I just edited my question, the other way I found seems to be almost working. I'm going to try your way at the moment! Thank you for your time

Comment: @MousKamel - just so you know `GetHashCode` doesn't guarantee it's the item you are looking for.

Comment: PersistentList<Article> la = new PersistentList<Article>();  is declared in my Home Cotnroller.  I did exactly what you've proposed but there is a problem.  it says impossible to use the type Article as parameter of type <T> in the type or generic method 'PersistentList<T>. There is no implict conversion reference.

Comment: @MousKamel - does `Article` implement the interface?

Comment: Sorry I'm still a noobie I forgot haha! Now it Works and yes, I had to use base.Find I see you modified it. Oh and in the generic Constraint new() has always to be the last one if this help anyone!  Thank you for your help Gilad Green!

Comment: @MousKamel - you are weolcome

Comment: @MousKamel - if you found the above useful please consider the marking as solved and/or upvoting

Comment: It was more than useful I realised a couple of things at the same time!